# How to check unique data

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my postgresql users table

```
create table users(
    id    serial primary key,
    name  text unique not null,
    email text unique not null,
    password text not null,
)
```

And this is my code to insert the user's data to the users table:

```
        String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES (?, ? ,?)";
        // Perform insertion.
        try {       
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertQuery);

            pstmt.setString(1, name);
            pstmt.setString(2, email);
            pstmt.setString(3, pwd);
            int rowCount = pstmt.executeUpdate();

            conn.commit();
            flag = true;
            conn.setAutoCommit(true);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();

            System.err.println(
                "There Is Something Wrong. I Don't Know Where. SOS...");
            flag = false;
        }
```

So because I set the name and the email in the database are unique, how can I verify if the user's data is violate the unique constraint in a friendly way? I understand that if there is no violation, the rowCount will return 1, otherwise, it will return 2. And if the rowCount is 2, it will fall into the catch block, then I am only able to catch the error as a whole but I dont know which value is violate the constraint.

For short, if the user's data violate the name's constraint, I want to display: "that username is already exist". Or if it only violates the email's constraint: "That email is already exist"

Comment: [Appendix A. PostgreSQL Error Codes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/errcodes-appendix.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you call getNextException when your exception has type SQLException, you'll get the message from Postgres that actually describes the error.

```
   catch (SQLException e) {
        String nextExceptionMessage = e.getNextException().getMessage();
        System.err.println(
            "Could not save the record:" + nextExceptionMessage);
        flag = false;
    }
```